# What's a polite way to ask my manager that if he has read my message?

Tags: email, manager, time-off

I am supposed to be married in April next year and my family back in India wants to start arrangements as soon as possible. For that I wanted to get an official confirmation that I can have 3 weeks off.

One of the things that complicate everything is that my manager works remotely and Slack/Email is the only way I can reach him.

Initially the date my family assumed the date would in Dec-Jan, so I asked him about that and he said if I can confirm the date that would be great. But our Priest has given us a date in April and messaged him yesterday morning confirming the date but he hasn't replied yet.

What would be the most polite way I can get a reply from him? Or do I wait?

Comment: [How to proceed when remote boss doesn't answer emails?](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21981)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be the most polite way I can get a reply from him? Or do I wait?

It has only been one day, so you should give him some time to reply. How much depends on the time he usually takes to respond (maybe a couple days at least).

If after a week or so you get no reply then you should definitely reply for follow up. If you do, remember to do it politely and clear on why the urge for the confirmation.

Meanwhile, what you can do to maximize your chances it to also send him the message via Slack and other tools you use to communicate with him in your company. If you do, try to be as polite as possible and explain your urge for confirmation.

Comment: its also possible he is already starting any required paper to make this all official even quick and just doesn't want to reply until everything is in order. I agree 1 week should be wait for follow up

Comment: Yes, it may be that he is already asking *his* superiors for clearance... those vertical processes take some time.

Comment: Even though he said he wouldn't have any issues giving me time off for my vacation since its my own wedding & its a pretty significant event.

Comment: @user3777390 even though he is OK with it, there is usually still protocol for the manager to request the time off

Comment: yes, which could be one of the reasons he is taking his time to respond (although again, one day is really short time). giving him more time to respond would be reasonable in this case